# What is the functions of slash in ruby

Tags: ruby, comments, slash

When I put slashes at the beginning and the end of the some code block in ruby they behave like comments. Why is that?

CODE

```
puts "hello"
/
puts "world"
/
puts "peace"
```

OUTPUT

```
hello
peace
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You create a multiline regexp here:

```
r = /
a
/
r.class
#=> Regexp
```

And in your case, you first puts `hello`, then you create a regex of

```
\\nputs "world"\\n
```

then you puts `peace`

Comment: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Regular+Expressions